# Generalized division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Motivated by this question: [What is the kernel of the evaluation homomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414391/what-is-the-kernel-of-the-evaluation-homomorphism) I would like to know where I can find more about such theorem in $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ instead of in $R[x]$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a vague question. What do you want to know?

Comment: See any good exposition on Grobner bases and related methods.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I would like to know if there is a kind of "division algorithm" in $R[x_1,...,x_n]$

Comment: $R[x]$ is not specifically mentioned in the link that you have provided. What do you have in mind? If $n \geq 2$, you don't have a division in general even if $R$ is a field.

Comment: @GilYoungCheong please, see the answers to this question.