# The ideal $\langle x-y+1,y-3\rangle$ of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

> I'm trying to show  that the ideal $I  =\langle x-y+1,y-3\rangle$ of the ring $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is maximal.

---

My approach so far:

We define $\phi:\mathbb C[x,y]\to \mathbb C,$ with mapping
$$f(x,y)\mapsto f(2,3).$$
We can easily prove that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism $\big($i.e  $f(x,y)=x-2+y-3+p(x,y)$, hence,  $\phi(f)=p(x,y)$ $\big)$.

Its enough to show that ker($\phi$)=$I.$
$$f\in\langle x-y+1,y-3\rangle:$$
$$f(x,y)=(x-y+1)g(x,y)+(y-3)h(x,y)\Rightarrow f(2,3)=0\Rightarrow f\in\text{ker}(\phi)\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow \langle x-y+1,y-3\rangle\subseteq \text{ker}(\phi).$$
But if $f\in\text{ker}(\phi):$ how can i show that $f(x,y)=(x-y+1)g(x,y)+(y-3)h(x,y)?$ 
In order to claim that $\mathbb C[x,y]/\operatorname{ker}(\phi)\cong\operatorname{im}(\phi)=\mathbb C$ ($\to$ field $\iff I $ is maximal)

I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: If you can show that $\langle x, y \rangle$ is maximal, then you are on the right track

Comment: First show that $I=\langle x-2, y-3\rangle$. Then use the division algorithm. For a hint, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/414440/732532

Comment: Yeah, that works really well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice trick which I really like. We can look what happens in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$. We have $y-3\in I$, and so $y+I=3+I$. Also:

$x+I=x-(x-y+1)+I=(y-1)+I=(3-1)+I=2+I$

From here it easily follows that for each $f\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ we have $f(x,y)+I=f(2,3)+I$. In particular, if $f\in \text{ker}(\phi)$ then $f+I=f(2,3)+I=I$, and so $f\in I$.

Comment: Cool trick, but i didn't understand the part: $f(x,y)+I=f(2,3)+I.$

Comment: Write explicitly $f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i,j} a_{ij}x^iy^j$. As we have shown, in the quotient ring $x$ turns into $2$ and $y$ turns into $3$, so $f(x,y)+I=\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{ij}2^i3^j+I=f(2,3)+I$.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's  a really nice trick that i'm gonna use from now on!

Comment: @rick more generally in $R[y]$ we have $\,(y\!-\!a,f(y)) = (y\!-\!a,f(a))\,$ by $\,f(y)\equiv f(a)\pmod{\!y-a},\,$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3933704/242). So $\,(y\!-\!3,x\!-\!y\!+\!1) = (y\!-\!3,x\!-\!2).\ \ $